# Data lost due to installation of Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery, data-loss

I was installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. While installing it showed the partition menu, and I selected some options that were told to me by Ubuntu users on Ask Ubuntu. I did the same, but I wasn't sure about that, so I quit the installation process and restarted my laptop. I let Windows start as normal, and then on opening *My Computer*, I saw that all the drives (hard disk D and E) were gone. I had a lot of important data on them. What do I do now? Is the data gone?

I have a 64-bit OS.

Comment: That is hard to say, since we have no idea what it is that you have done. Could you startup from the cd again, open gparted and send a (link to) a screenshot of what gparted shows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your data is most likely gone. Most likely your data drive was reformatted as a home for Ubuntu. This means that the actual Ubuntu installation could have been placed on top of other data, rendering at least some of it irrecoverable.

There is some limited good news however. There are a number of different programs that can be used to recover data. The [Ubuntu DataRecovery Community Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) should be a good start to recovering what can be recovered.

A final bit of warning if you choose to recover the data. Avoid using your newly installed Linux, as writes to that partition will possibly minimize the chance of successful recovery.

Comment: thanx for the reply. I searched for most of the data like documents, movies, games, etc. that I had in my drives.. for my surprize, a kind of warning messg says "the drive or network connection that the shortcut to the file refers to is UNAVAILABLE. make sure that disk is properly inserted or network resource is available, and then try again."..   I think data is there but the drives are not showing..

Comment: That message just means that Windows can't find the drive. If the drive has been repartitioned, that error would be expected.

From your Linux installation, open the command line and run "mount". Also run "df -h". That should tell us a little about the drives being used for your installation.